# Transit query Delhi-London-Dublin-Toronto 16 August 2023

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, london, toronto, dublin

I have ticket booking and have a query if layover at 2 airports. I will be highly obliged if u can respond to my query or share contact who can solve my query.

My itinerary is - Passport and nationality- INDIAN Valid Visitor visa - CANADA

British airways ticket DEL-TORONTO /single pnr

Delhi dep 01:35 am

London arrival 06:50 dep 09:50 (layover 3 hours)

Dublin arrival 11:15 dep 13:30 ( layover 2 hour 15 mins ) Will I require a transit visa on both airports because all persons I asked have different opinion.even airlines are not sure about this query. Last time I went outside Heathrow as I had 20 hours layover so I got transit visa at London airport, this time I don’t have to go outside and have shorter layovers. Kindly confirm actual status if possible.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times on multiple websites including this one but never answered conclusively resolving the query. The problem is the London-Dublin flight (Common Travel Area). The UKVI website states that an Indian citizen needs a visitor visa for the UK (not a transit visa) for this. This is different from a London-Toronto flight where you can be granted a discretionary leave to enter the UK for a short time on account of your Canadian visa. Unless we get first hand experience from travelers, the official website states you need a standard visitor visa from the UK.